# How to restore my Local database to Windows Azure Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have uploaded my application to Windows Azure Now I want to store My Local database to Windows Azure Database.

Please Suggest me how do I create table and backup the table there?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do that:

1. The most reliable (that I usually use) is using the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/)
2. Then you have the "Generate Scripts" option in your SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 or later). The generate Scripts option does have a feature to make SQL Azure compliant script. It can also script data. But I suggest using method one if you want to migrate data, too. SQL Azure Migration Wizard uses BCP tool, which dumps the data into binary files, while SSMS just generates inline INSERT Statements
3. SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) - you can create a Data Transfer task, but I would use it very rare for small DBs.
4. Export/Import data tier application (using DACPAC package) - this will migrate your schema and can migrate your data as well.

**UPDATE** 2017-10-24

Azure SQL Database now supports transactional replication from your on-premises SQL Server. You can configure your Azure SQL Database as subscriber and your SQL Server on-premise as publisher. You can read more about database migration options and strategies here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate

**Update 2017-12-23**

SQL Azure Migration Wizard has been replaced by Data Migration Assistant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate

Comment: I tried using SQL Server 2014 tools for the job but I was not successful. The SQL Azure Migration Wizard was the one that did the job properly.

Comment: In a second migration a few days later, the `SQL Azure Migration Wizard` did not help. The solution ended up being: extracting a data-tier from the **Local SQL Server** (using `Visual Studio SQL Server Object Explorer`) and then publish that same file in **Azure SQL Database** (also using `Visual Studio SQL Server Object Explorer`) and selecting the checkbox **Register as a Data-tier Application** and check **Allow incompatible platform** in advanced options. Worked really fine!

Comment: I am amazed how people come in 2017 and downvote answers given in 2011. But in that particular case I will still answer that the most reliable way to move SQL Database to Azure SQL DB is using the SQL Azure Migration Wizard. Unless you look for non-downtime migration.

Comment: SQL Azure Migration Wizard has been replaced by Data Migration Assistant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate

Answer (score 25):

If you already have a database on local machine then you can migrate it directly on Azure using SQL Management Studio. Follow these steps:

1. Right click on the database name in SSMS

[image]

2. Follow the wizard that appears then

Comment: do you need anything other than the IP when connecting to azure? do you need a port?

Comment: No you just need the credentials of your SQL Azure account to connect to Azure in SSMS. In Azure Portal, you should have added your IP to access the DB using the Firewall settings in SQL Azure.

Comment: This worked well for me, but you have to be somewhat careful about what users are associated with the database. Any Windows-based users or services will cause the process to error out. Once you remove them it's all good to go again.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways in which to achieve this functionality.

1. [SQL Azure Import/Export. "DACPAC" & "BACPAC"](http://sqldacexamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/72388)
2. [Microsoft Codename "Data Transfer"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlazurelabs/labs/datatransfer.aspx)
3. <strike>[SQL Azure Data Sync](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/tour/database-management/)</strike> [Windows Azure SQL Data Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh456371.aspx)
4. [Migrating Databases using Import/Export Wizard in SSMS](http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2010/12/14/Migrating-Large-Databases-from-On-Premise-to-SQL-Azure.aspx)
5. [SQL Azure Migration Wizard (As Mentioned in other Answers)](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Sorry if this is resurrecting an old topic, but some of these links are now outdated and no longer available.

Comment: There was only one link that is unavailable, it has now been updated.

Comment: thanks. Also, the Microsoft Codename "Data Transfer" lab phase is complete, I couldn't see anything from that page related to it, just assumed it's now outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're referring to SQL Azure?  If so, you'll probably want to use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard @ http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012 Management Studio and SQL Azure Tools also now has this option I believe.

In SSMS if you right click on the Databases root, there is an option "Import Data-tier Application...", which allows you to restore a BACPAC (you can also right click on a database, and select "Export Data-tier Application..." to export an existing database to a BACPAC).

SQL Server Data Tools enables Visual Studio 2010 with a Data Compare option, which can also be used to move data between two database instances (which would be suited to smaller data patches).